# Testing method signatures in Node.js

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, tdd, mocha.js, chai

I'm relatively new to Unit-testing and TDD specificly and am about to start my first project with TDD using mocha and chai.

Am I supposed to test the existence and parameter length of the methods?
And if so, is there any better way of doing it than I currently am? It feels extremly verbose, especially when repeating this for most of my classes.

For understand I've set up some dummy test.

`test/index.js`

```
'use strict';

const assert = require('chai').assert;

const Test = require('../lib/index.js');

describe('Test', function() {
    it('should be a function without parameters', function() {
        assert.isFunction(Test);
        assert.lengthOf(Test, 0);
    });

    let test;
    beforeEach(function() {
        test = new Test();
    });

    describe('static#method1', function() {
        it('should have static method method1 with 1 parameter', function() {
            assert.property(Test, 'method1');
            assert.isFunction(Test.method1);
            assert.lengthOf(Test.method1, 1);
        });
        it('should assert on non-string parameters', function() {
            const params = [
              123,
              {},
              [],
              function() {}
            ];
            params.forEach(function(param) {
                assert.throws(function() {
                    Test.method1(param)
                });
            });
        });
        it('should return "some value"', function() {
            assert.equal(Test.method1('param'), 'some value')
        });
    });
    describe('method2', function() {
        it('should have method method2 with 2 parameters', function() {
            assert.property(test, 'method2');
            assert.isFunction(test.method2);
            assert.lengthOf(test.method2, 2);
        });
        it('should assert on non-number parameters', function() {
            const params = [
                'some string',
                {},
                [],
                function() {}
            ];
            params.forEach(function(param) {
                assert.throws(function() {
                    test.method2(param)
                });
            });
        });
        it('should add the parameters', function() {
            assert.equal(test.method2(1, 2), 3);
            assert.equal(test.method2(9, -2), 7);
            assert.equal(test.method2(3, -12), -9);
            assert.equal(test.method2(-7, -5), -12);
        })
    });
});
```

And the tested implementation.

`lib/index.js`

```
'use strict';

const assert = require('chai').assert;

exports = module.exports = (function() {
    class Test {
        static method1(param0) {
            assert.typeOf(param0, 'string');
            return 'some value';
        }

        method2(param0, param1) {
            assert.typeOf(param0, 'number');
            assert.typeOf(param1, 'number');
            return param0 + param1;
        }
    }

    return Test;
}());
```

Comment: Testing function signatures is ok in some cases, but under certain conditions it can be really hard to maintain and can hinder further development by frequently breaking tests every time the API changes, even just in an additive way. When the argument order matters a lot (function wrapped in an async.waterfall, etc) then it can yield some benefits, but overall I haven't found it to be that useful. However, testing the runtime effects of these functions is much easier with something like http://sinonjs.org/. I would take a look at the spies and stubs/mocks as they can really help here.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, I'll definitely take a look at SinonJs.

Answer (score 0):

No, such detailed tests are not necessary. What is the value of them? What do they help you to achieve?

Usually when testing functions we test behavior of a function, not its implementation. Implementation can completely change without changing the observable behavior: for example, you can find more readable way to rewrite your code or a more performant algorithm.

You test the call signature of your function by the whole set of tests for it, indirectly. Every *test provides an example of how to use your function*, thus ensuring its call signature and return parameters.